# Shiny dynamically create reactive data.table basis selected variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, data.table, summarize

I am creating an app that will take dynamic inputs from the user and should generate bar and line charts. In order to have proper percentages of the bars I feel I need to summarize my data. Since my data is huge I am using data.table.

What I am looking for is variable selected in row should be my x-axis and y-axis should be used for calculating percentages (denominator). Scale to be 100%. I have created a sample data to depict the situation.

Below is the Shiny code that I am using -

```
library("shiny")
library("ggplot2")
library("scales")
library("data.table")
library("plotly")

Location <- sample(1:5,100,replace = T)
Brand <- sample(1:3,100,replace = T)
Year <- rep(c("Year 2014","Year 2015"),50)
Q1 <- sample(1:5,100,replace = T)
Q2 <- sample(1:5,100,replace = T)

mydata <- as.data.table(cbind(Location,Brand,Year,Q1,Q2))

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    fluidRow(
      column(10,
             div(style = "font-size: 13px;", selectInput("rowvar", label = "Select Row Variable", ''))
      ),
      tags$br(),
      tags$br(),
      column(10,
             div(style = "font-size: 13px;", selectInput("columnvar", "Select Column Variable", ''))
      ))

  ),
  tabPanel("First Page"),
  mainPanel(tabsetPanel(id='charts',
                        tabPanel("charts",tags$b(tags$br("Graphical Output" )),tags$br(),plotlyOutput("plot1"))
  )
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session){
  updateTabsetPanel(session = session
                    ,inputId = 'myTabs')

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "rowvar", choices = (as.character(colnames(mydata))),selected = "mpg")
  })

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "columnvar", choices = (as.character(colnames(mydata))),selected = "cyl")
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    validate(need(input$rowvar,''),
             need(input$columnvar,''))
countdd <- mydata[,.N,by=.(get(input$rowvar),get(input$columnvar))]
sumdd <- countdd[,sum(N),get(input$columnvar)]
propdd <- countdd$N/sumdd$V1[match(paste0("countdd$",get(input$columnvar)),paste0("sumdd$",get(input$columnvar)))]
countdd$prop <- round(propdd*100,2)

ggplot(countdd,aes(x=get(input$rowvar),y=prop)) + geom_bar(stat = 'sum')

  })

})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But when I run this code it give me error - **Error: 
The items in the 'by' or 'keyby' list are length (100). Each must be same length as rows in x or number of rows returned by i (6).**

How can I create a reactive data.table so that I can use the same to generate my bar and line plots. Can't we pass dynamic variables in i,j and by part of data.table?

Please suggest !!

Comment: I can get rid of your main error by not using get(), 'countdd <- mydata[,.N,by=c(input$rowvar, input$columnvar)]', the plot will show with no data. I'm still puzzled at what you are trying to do with propdd. In other words, why are you using get() ?

Comment: @Dan, Yes, without get plot is showing no data. This gave me a feeling that data is not getting created and I started using get() post doing some search on stackoverflow. How ever did not get any post of usage of get in data.table with Shiny and started getting that error. Basically I am looking for a plot, that would give percentages basis the calculation, **Brand1 / Year1*100**, something that this table would give, `prop.table(table(mydata$Brand,mydata$Year),2)`. Is there a way to get this without summarizing data? and yes, the plot should get updated basis the input variable selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use character vectors (like `input$rowvar`) in `data.table` expressions via `eval()`. If you want a plot that summarizes data like `prop.table(table(mydata$Brand,mydata$Year),2)` so that the sum of all three brands totals 1 each year:

```
    Year 2014 Year 2015
  1      0.48      0.38
  2      0.24      0.32
  3      0.28      0.30
```

then try this (total is 100):

```
  output$plot1 <- renderPlotly({
    validate(need(input$rowvar,''),
             need(input$columnvar,''))
    countdd <- mydata[, .(n = .N), by = eval(c(input$rowvar, input$columnvar))]
    sumdd <- countdd[, .(total = sum(n, na.rm = TRUE)), by = eval(c(input$rowvar))]
    setkeyv(countdd, input$rowvar)
    setkeyv(sumdd, input$rowvar)
    propdd <- sumdd[countdd]
    propdd[, proportion := round(100 * n / total, 2)]
    ggplot(propdd, aes_string(x = input$rowvar, y = "proportion",
      fill = input$columnvar)) + geom_bar(stat = 'sum')
  })
```

which produces this plot when `year` is row variable and `brand` is column variable in the `shiny` app:

[image: summarized data]